# Private C++ member function vs C function

Tags: c++, c, private-members

I have a C++ class, and in one of the member functions there is a duplicate section of code. So I've extracted this out into a function, however only this member function will call this new function. At the moment it's just a c function defined in the cpp file and not declared anyway else.

Is there any advantage to making this a private C++ member function, the code in the function itself doesn't use any instead variables of the class.

Comment: You made a good design decision.

Comment: Related: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if you posted a simplified code sample. Certainly the cognitive load required to read this would be smaller.

Comment: Whack it in a lambda and leave it private to the function itself until such time as it's needed outside?

Comment: @Leushenko Wouldn't this decrease performance? This is in a function that is called every frame in a video and is heavy in performance (detecting parts of faces)

Comment: @Jonathan., lambdas have no impact on performance. They are simply ad-hoc defined functions. They might affect program size, though.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if it's any addition to the argument, the newest [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) say that you should "[C.5: Place helper functions in the same namespace as the class they support](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#-c5-place-helper-functions-in-the-same-namespace-as-the-class-they-support)". So they shouldn't be a part of the actual class, but part of the namespace that they reside in.

Answer (score 1):

If you add it to the class then it becomes part of the classes signature.
As such making changes to the function signature would change the class signature. Given it would be a private function it is not likely that you would gain much by exposing it in that way.

If though it needs to access internals of the class then having as part of the class would likely simplify its implementation.

If it does not need to access the internals you can make add it to an anonymous namespace within the cpp file. That way the function symbol will not be exposed anywhere that is is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

(Sort of an extended comment)

You've declared a free function in the .cpp file.
This a good design decision as other answers point out. The clearest thing you can have is a method only visible from that .cpp file that can't see or change state. I might be tempted to put it in the same namespace as the class as per the CppCoreGuidelines.

Equivilently, you could have declared a `private static` member function in your header file. This is `static` in the C#/Java sense rather than in either of the C senses ([C++ has all of these meanings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141871/false-friends-keyword-static-in-c-compared-to-c-c-and-java)). However, I don't see the benifit as the only thing you gain is unnecessary recompilations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Putting the function in class defines scope and context of it. This makes maintenance easier and also will allow you to extend its functionality in the future without significant code rewriting. Actually, in such cases I usually prefer making the function static in the class, i.e., meeting somewhere in the middle.

Comment: But I will have to add it to the class definition in the header (although private this seems like exposing implementation details too much)

Comment: Not true. The article by Sott Meyers in DDJ mentioned in one of the comments is worth a read.

Comment: @Jonathan. If it's important to you, it can be avoided by other techniques (see pimpl)

Comment: @RSahu Well, I'm entitled to my own opinion, even in front of Scott Meyers, don't I?

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername, we all are. If you haven't read the article, please do. It might change your opinion. I happen to agree with Scott Meyers' assessments.

Comment: We are not gender studies majors, we are software developers, so it should rarely be about difference of opinions. There are defined benefits of prefering free-standing functions to class members.

Comment: Actually turns out I do need to access instance variables, so I've had to make it a member function, and add it to the header. (coming from objective-c, putting a private method in a public header makes me want to cry).

Comment: @Jonathan, don't cry. I have a solution for you. It is called pimpl. I hate pimpl, of course. But you might fall in love with it.

Comment: @SergeyA It's funny that everyone addresses Meyers' article but no one addresses my actual answer.

Comment: @Jonathan. Assuming it's not a lot of class state you could always pass the state to the non-member function.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername, which part of your answer remained unadressed?

Comment: @SergeyA, I've seen pimpl, and fell in hate with it.

Comment: @Jonathan., OK. So you do not want to use pimpl, and you do not want to declare your private functions in the class header. Looks like C++ is not for you! :)

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername, at the top I said I didn't like the idea of putting it in the class definition in the header

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername, you are suggesting to put a function into the class (as static member, I see) and we do believe in the generic case it is better to be left free-standing. What's not addressed?

Comment: @SergeyA, I really like a lot of C++, it is just this that I dislike severely. (though if I had a choice I'd be writing this in objective-c)

Comment: @Jonathan. So you shouldn't like private functions at all. That's the way C++ natively works.

Comment: @JamesAdkison, I thought about that, but it's about 5 different instance variables. I guess passing the instance (this) as the first parameter (like it is behind the scenes with member functions, wouldn't be a nice idea?

Comment: @Jonathan. on many accounts, C++ is not a true OO language (now feed me to the wolves), which actually makes it a perfect choice for me. I specifically enjoy it's non-OO.

Comment: @SergeyA  I gave at least 2 reasons for keeping it in class. "Believe" is not a valid contr-argument. Appealing to authority (Meyers) also isn't a valid argument

Comment: @SergeyA, actually before I started doing anything in C++ I wrote a compiler (uni group project) for a custom language that would be how I wanted a language to be, and then when I got to C++ found there were quite a lot of things in it that I had liked. Just telling the world about private implementation is not good. An equivalent to objective-c extensions and I'd be completely in love with C++.

Comment: @Jonathan. Passing the class instance is fine but obviously the non-member function won't have access to non-public state/functions (i.e., you'd have to declare it a friend of the class which may not be appealing to you).

Comment: Putting a function which has nothing to do with the class into the class ensures all users of the class need to recompile their code when the new function is added (even if they never call it!), and relink when implemtation changed. On the other hand, free-standing function the separate .cpp is not even pulled unless used. To me this is an immediate benefit.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't see major differences here. The function is definitely used in class (otherwise there is no justification putting it there) - it's called by some other in-class function (e.g., to do some generic math that doesn't depend on class properties but rather on input). See the original question, it's just a factoring out a piece of common code.